# Allah names that correspond to Omniscient, Omnipresent, Omnipotent, Omnibenevolent

Tags: asma-ul-husna

Western philosophers use terms Omniscient, Omnipresent, Omnipotent, Omnibenevolent while discussing about God.

I would say that Omniscient corresponds to al-Alim (All-Knowing), and I would guess that al-Wadud would correspond to Omnibenevolent (All-Loving). And I would guess that al-Qaadir corresponds to Omnipotent (All-Powerful). Which Quranic name of Allah corresponds to Omnipresent (All-Present---that Allah is everywhere.)?

(Western philosophers also invariably use the term All-Good (especially when discussing the so-called problem of evil). To my limited understanding, there is no such attribute of Allah in Quran, am I correct? **Note:** I am not attributing anything to Allah; just asking whether Quran involves a name of Allah that simply means All-Good.)

Comment: Allahs attributes are more than just "Asma'u l-Llah al-Husna", one could give an answer with several verses where the omnipresence of Allah is expressed by his attributes, but not his "beautiful names". And one could do so even without quoting both.

Comment: @Medi1Saif♦ I am aware of that. I am not questioning whether Allah is All-Present or not, or whether Allah is All-Good or not. Just that to my knowledge All-Good is not part of His "Beautiful Names" (I have a theory why), but wanted to check whether I missed something.

Answer (score 2):

Assaluma haleikum achi

First of all you don't have to defend yourself. Your question was clear enough to conclude you're were interested in that particular name of Allah and nothing else.

Second of all (the answer):

I'd choose between الباسط ( Al-Basit -  the Expander, the Munificent, the One who stretches out) or الواسع (Al-Wasi- the Vast, the All Encompassing, All-embracing).

I hope this answered your question.

Source:

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:The_99_names_of_Allah

Comment: @blackened: Isn't this sufficient? It seemed you were only looking for a name so I thought the answer could as well be short.

Answer (score 0):

Quran surah 57 ayah 4(Wherever you are Allah is with you), Quran surah 50 ayah 16(Allah is near to man than to his jugular vein)....Check these verses and is it not shows the omnipresence of Allah also in Asma ul husna Al-basit or Al-wasi Check✔